# Python - iterate through nested json and save values

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I have a nested JSON (API) webstie which i want to parse and save items to file (using Scrapy framework).

I want to access each subelement of given elements, those are in following format

```
0   {…}
1   {…}
2   {…}
3   {…}
4   {…}
5   {…}
6   {…}
7   {…}
8   {…}
9   {…}
10  {…}
```

If I expand element 0 i get following values, where {...} exapnds further

```
id  6738
date    "2018-06-14T09:38:51"
date_gmt    "2018-06-14T09:38:51"
guid    
     rendered   "https:example.com"
modified    "2019-03-19T20:43:50"
modified_gmt    "2019-03-19T20:43:50"
```

[How does it look like in reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvvgN.png)

How do I access, consecutively, each element, first 0, then 1, then 2 ... up to total of 350 and grab value of, for example

```
guid   
    rendered "https//:example.com"
```

and save it to item.

What I have:

```
       results = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
       item = DataItem()
       for var in results:
           item['guid'] = results["guid"]
       yield item
```

This fails with

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

I know that i can access it with

`item['guid'] = results[0]["guid"]`

But this only gives me [0] index of the whole list and I want to iterate through all of indexes. How do I pass index number inside of the list?

Comment: *But this only gives me [0] index of the whole list* how about replacing `0` with something uhm, like a variable? or the length?

Comment: Post a sample of `results` to get instant help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `results["guid"]` in your for loop to `var["guid"]`:

```
for var in results:
    item['guid'] = var["guid"]
    # do whatever you want with item['guid'] here
```

when you can access `guid` like `results[0]["guid"]` it means that you have list of dictionaries that every dictionary contains key named `guid`. in your for loop you use `results` (that is list) instead of `var` (that contain every dictionary in each iteration) that throws `TypeError` because list indices must be integers not strings (like `"guid"`).

**UPDATE:** if you want to save each `var["guid"]` you can save them in a dictionary like this:

```
guid_holder = {"guid": []}
for var in results:
    guid_golder["guid].append(var["guid"])
for guid in guid_holder["guid"]:
    print(guid)
```

now `guid_holder` holds all elements.

Comment: I've done this. It behaves weirdly. Gives only one results from 10th index. ````results[0]["guid']```` behaves correctly, prints ````guid```` for element [0]. ````results```` keeps whole json webpage in variable, i can print it too by using ````print(results)````. I don't know how to iterate through every [0,1,2,3...] and get ````guid```` for each.

Comment: @Alex16237 What exactly `results` contains ? please add it as an example to your question

Comment: I've posted a picture (edited post). Can't get formatting right with this one as there are too many elements.

Comment: @Alex16237 I updated my answer see section UPDATE for saving all elements

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Maybe i phrase it badly. How do I pass variable/lenght of an array to index inside of the loop? I think this is how I solve this problem, ie. ````item['guid'] = results[*]["guid"]```` where ````*```` is variable passed by a loop. ````results```` reads whole page, if I call it with ````print```` i get ful JSON parsed page.

Comment: @Alex16237 you can exactly do this with `guid_holder`  dictonary in my UPDATE section of answer

Comment: Correct! API was at fault, i tested your solution locally, without grabbing content from web and it works perfectly (formatting is a little off however). API was limiting list returned.